# Can I save my brother in Dragon Age 2?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In the beginning of Dragon Age 2,

> your brother dies in one of the first fights.

Is there any way to save him or is this a scripted event that can't be avoided?

Comment: Actually for me, Hawke's sister Bethany died. Not Carver. I didn't know until now that who dies depends on Hawke's class. I was a mage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Dragon Age Wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Carver), it sounds like the character that dies is based on Hawke's class. This is probably to aid in giving the player a balanced party without too many redundant classes.

Comment: To be precise, Carver dies if Hawke is a rogue or a warrior. If Hawke is a mage, Bethany will die instead.